# SetSecure to true for a Cookie

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, cookies, spring-security

I am trying to create a `cookie` with `SetSecure` as `true`. This is creating problem in save or update methods and systems redirect to error page/ throw 403 error. If I remove `SetSecure` then it's working fine.

```
Cookie ck= new Cookie("key",value);
ck.setsecure(true);

response.addCookie(ck);// HttpResponse
```

**Q1)** Is it okay to just set `secure flag to true`? Or do I have to take care of some more changes in my `webapp`?

**Q2)** I am using `http` to connect to my `webapp`. Is this `SetSecure flag` works with `http protocol`? Or it has to be `Https`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cookie with the secure flag to true  only means that the browser in the other side won't send it to the server if the connection is unencrypted (eg. in http protocol).["The purpose of the secure flag is to prevent cookies from being observed by unauthorized parties due to the transmission of a the cookie in clear text."](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag)

So in you're case, the cookie will never be sent back to the server after being created, that's why you are getting an error. If you really need to use this flag for whatever reason, you should use an https server.

Comment: I am using a https. But i still get this 403 error.

Comment: how to test this if my cookie.setsecure() is really set to true

Comment: @ShubhroMukherjee, in the browser's dev tool, Networking tab, you can check all the headers of any requests and responses, for example a secure cookie could look like this: _Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=someId123; Path=/; HttpOnly; **Secure**; SameSite=strict_